# when a condition is true, I have to change the next line in the text file

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a text file where I have to add the grid view values to it based on the sensor values. If the condition is true, I have to replace the next line of it. 
However I can able to replace the files in series irrespective of the value check.

the condition is checking one line and replacing some other line which has the same string. But my problem is I have replace the next line where the condition was true.

For your information. Here is the sample list of input  file

```
DASensor.0.name = S1
DASensor.0.pos = 3.734 0.805 0.495
DASensor.0.rot = 0.0 1 69.0039
DASensor.0.alpha = 120
DASensor.0.theta = 30
DASensor.0.range = 5.0
DASensor.0.UpdRate = 1000
DASensor.0.nCycleOffset = 0
DASensor.0.tracking = ClosestObject
DASensor.0.CalcClass = ImageArea
DASensor.0.movietheme = Orange
DASensor.0.Mounting = Fr1A
DASensor.0.ShowDDict = 0
DASensor.0.ExtMotion = 0
```

the above text lines is a sensor file where i have to replace the values
`DASensor.0.pos = x y z` where x y z are my values that i have to update from gridview. 
Like this there will be 12 sensor positions. 
based on the `DASensor.0.name = S1`, I have to replace the values of `DASensor.0.pos`.

So far I have tried this and can able to change the values but cant able change  based on the condition.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\RAG4ABT\Desktop\test.txt"));

int rowcount = metroGrid8.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    int lineIndex = lines.FindIndex(line => line.StartsWith("DASensor." + i + ".pos = "));
    int lineIndex1 = lines.FindIndex(line => line.StartsWith("DASensor." + i + ".rot = "));
    //if (("DASensor." +i+".name = S"+j) == ("DASensor." +i+".name = " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
    //{
    if ((("DASensor." + i + ".name = S" + j) == ("DASensor." + i + ".name = " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())) && (lineIndex != -1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Happy");
        lines[lineIndex] = "DASensor." + i + ".pos = " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + " " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\RAG4ABT\Desktop\test.txt", lines);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: ya. i tried debugging, it checks some other line and the condition is true, since it is available and updates. But it is not updating the next line where the condition is true

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question a bit?  You have a data grid view that you are using as a source to write a file?  Did you use the debugger and step through the code and identify which line is failing?   If it's your IF statement, then troubleshoot that.  You can get all in the info you need about your variables from the debugger.

Comment: Put `("DASensor." + i + ".name = S" + j)` and `("DASensor." + i + ".name = " + metroGrid8.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())` into separate variables above the IF statement, put a breakpoint on them and compare the values.

Comment: @Missy: the condition is checking and returns true. But my Question is how to change the very next line where the condition is true. For ex. if the condition is true on line 2, i have to change the line 3. However, I can check for line3 and change it. But that doesnt be correct for this scenario.

Comment: @try_cod Create a model for `Sensor` containing some properties like `Pos`, `Name`, ... and then edit sensors in a `DataGridView` and then save data from `DataGridview`.